# Python список словарей в один словарь

Tags: python, list, dict

**Дано:**

Список словарей, например `dict_list = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3}]`

**Требуется (если возможно)**:

Наиболее коротко слить словари в один

Если возможно, с помощью примерно такого пробега по списку:

```
{(some actions with e) for e in dict_list}
```

Как такое сделать?

Гарантируется, что разные словари в списке не содержат одинаковых полей

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Кратко

```py
{k: v for d in dict_list for k, v in d.items()}
```

Но так будет быстрее, если это важно

```py
result = {}
for d in dict_list:
  result.update(d)
```